# why my laptop display doesn't turn back on after screen turning off for power saving

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, display, asus-laptop

I am using windows 10 1709 with nvidia and intel hd gpus (Asus Laptop)
so when I log out and leave my laptop for a while the screen goes off
the problem is that sometimes it wont turn back on whatever I do , it seems as the laptop keyboard and mouse stops responding and the only thing that turns it back on it to plug the power cable.

It doesn't happen every time but it is occuring a lot recently.

Have anyone before faced this problem and can tell the cause or the solution ???
it is becoming quiet frustrating

Comment: 1) why still 1709 & 2) precisely which chipset? "Intel HD" bothers me, because most of them are unsupported in WIn10.

Comment: I am updating to 1909 now to see if windows version is the problem ,,,,,
the intel gpu is intel Hd 620

Comment: ah, OK. The 620 is fully supported still, so that's not the source of the issue, at least.